# Wordcount error using Python

Tags: python, hadoop

I am running word count program in hadoop with below command

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar -file /home/Hadoop/Python/mapper.py -mapper mapper.py  -file /home/Hadoop/Python/reducer.py -reducer reducer.py -input "/Hadoop/Hive.txt" -output "/Hadoop/output.txt"
```

And below error causing the failure of the program

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1427776730247_0008/container_1427776730247_0008_01_000006/./mapper.py":
>   error=2, No such file or directory

I think these are runtime directories created and yarn is having read write permission for this directory.

Do I need to manually change permission for these directories and place mapper and reducer file there?